# Generate scripts automatically by giving object names in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In sql server 2005/2008, can anyone please advise me on how can i generate scripts automatically of all the objects that let say starts with "Client_"

I already have a query that identifies all the object that starts from "client_", but i also want to generate there scripts automatically. Doing it manually is a huge task.

```
select name,type_desc
from sys.objects
where object_definition(object_id) like '%client_%'
```

Please advise

Massive thanks
Amit

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use [`sp_helptext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176112.aspx) system procedure within your select statement.
Also you could use database cursor to perform execution of `sp_helptext` in a loop:

```
DECLARE @name SYSNAME -- object name  
DECLARE @type_desc VARCHAR(MAX) -- path for backup files  
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
select name,type_desc
from sys.objects
where object_definition(object_id) like '%client_%'

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name, @type_desc  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
    SET @sql = 
    'sp_helptext @objname = ''' + @name + ''''

    EXEC (@sql)

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name, @type_desc 
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Additional solution is to use [`sys.syscomments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186293.aspx) system view. Example:

```
SELECT o.name, o.[type], s.[text]
from sys.objects o
INNER JOIN sys.syscomments s ON o.[object_id] = s.id
where object_definition(object_id) like '%client_%'
```

Answer (score -1):

I think there is not tool that will solve your purpose. else use generate script for all and remove extra script that you don't need.

Comment: well i have got thousands of scripts. anyways thanks for looking into my question

Comment: it's ok that's my opinion only.